# How to concatenate day month and year into a string

Tags: vb.net, vb6

```
Dim b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 As String
con1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\FM-DB1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    rs1.Open "select * from New_Family", con1, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    rs1.MoveFirst
    While rs1.EOF <> True
        If rs1.Fields(1).Value = frmReport.cmbRegNo.Text Then
            b1 = rs1.Fields(10).Value '---Day---
            b2 = "-"
            b3 = rs1.Fields(11).Value '---Month---
            b4 = "-"
            b5 = rs1.Fields(12).Value '---Year---

            **frmReport.lstDOB.AddItem (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5)**
        End If  
        rs1.MoveNext
    Wend
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unprecise. I will write here some ideas you can work with: when dealing with dates, it is usually better to not rely on strings, but on date/time types (e.g., in VB.NET, you might create a `DateTime` from the day, month and year values); use these variables to perform all the calculations/modifications you need in the code; when printing out the values, you can rely on the multiple in-built options to convert these types into strings with different formats (e.g., in VB.NET, yourDateTimeVar.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") or with any other format you wish)...

Comment: ... That is, ideally, you wouldn't need to concatenate elements to output a date (time) value, but just rely on the right types and perform the required conversions between them. On the other hand, to concatenate string values to form a bigger string, you might also rely on different approaches (in VB.NET there are various alternatives, you should do some research). Note that there are different reason to prefer one approach over other one, but performance is not one of them (unless under extreme conditions) -> a common misconception...

Comment: ...Lastly when dealing with databases, it is usually better to rely on parameterised arguments than on concatenated strings; to avoid things like SQL injection (by bearing in mind that it might also be avoided with properly-built strings). You would be accounting for this issue here in case of relying on the proposed date/time variable (this is basically what parameterised queries are about: replacing strings with the most adequate types for each situation). I hope that you will understand (at least, part) of these ideas and that, from now, you will use SO properly (= proper questions).

Answer (score 0):

In VB to concatenate values you would use `&` (ampersand), so your code, after corrections, would be:

```
frmReport.lstDOB.AddItem (b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 & b5)
```

The way you had it would try and add (b1 plus b2 plus b3, etc.) but this fails because some of your variables contain an operator (minus sign). You can't perform addition on an operator of course :-)